# How can I use and display the same image shown as Launch Image for an iOS app in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, launchimage

I would like to use exactly the same image that appears at the launch of the app, to display it in my first scene and put over it an activity indicator.

I've seen that in `./ios/<app name>/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage` there are all the images used for the launch, and there's a JSON file containing informations about which image file to use, but how can I know which is my case (orientation, device)?

Any suggestions? Thank you very much, I'm using React Native.

Answer (score 0):

let the image be parent in the render():

`render() {
    return (
      <Image source={require('./yourImagepath/image.png')} style=
        {styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View>
          ....
        </View>
      </Image>
    );
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        backgroundImage: {
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
       },
    }
}`

Comment: That's not what I need dude :D my app is ready, I've created the whole app from scratch. The only thing I haven't been able to do yet is to _get_ the correct image to display, the same shown as Launch Image.